# How to add the add reaction button to a message with discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

[image: how to implement the circled blue part of this image]

I want the members of my discord server to be able to react to a bot message with any emoji (using the winking smiling emoji with a plus sign). I have been looking for add reaction option in the discord.py [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.emojis) but I can't seem to find it. Please help me with this, it will be a great help.

Comment: It’s added automatically.

Comment: More like it depends on the permissions for the members in that exact channel, not on the message sent by the bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding reactions isn't a permission given on a per-message basis, it is set in the channel settings as "Add reactions". It's not something you should want to change automatically with your bot, though technically you could with [`set_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions) in a guild channel, this will change the settings for the whole channel, and thus all the messages.